# How to create multiple frames in a single frame to display input as welll as output?

Tags: python, frames

I am creating a programs that detects number of fingers and displays them. 
Further I'll be updating it to addition of multiple digit numbers. 
I saw this video on youtube and I wonder how he managed to split his input and output screen into 2 different screens? 
my current program displays the text in the frame itself

.[image]

in the given picture he has divided his output screen into 2 screens one that displays the video cam and another displays its output. 
I need help to understand how he did it?

Comment: Why don’t you ask the poster directly?

Comment: I have seen his comments on the youtube video and he is not that regular at replying. I am in a hurry to complete my project so I though I'd post it on stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0):

i assume you are using pycv

if you use np.vstack or np.hstack you can see the stacked images.

Comment: is it possible to create such frames where one frame handles the video and another frame shows the output? 
He did that in a single output screen which is divided into 2 parts.( video cam and output )

Comment: once you create the window you can use a buffer with x,y pos to stream video too