# ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 270000 into shape (1,100,100,3)

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I am trying to predict my hand posture using a live video. But when I compile my program this error occurs `" ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 270000 into shape (1,100,100,3) "`

```
import traceback
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math
from numpy import loadtxt
from keras.models import load_model

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
classifier = load_model('hand_gest.h5')
while(1):
    try:
        ret, frame = cam.read()
        frame = cv2.flip(frame,1)
        roi = frame[100:400,200:500]
        cv2.rectangle(frame,(200,100),(500,400),(0,255,0),2) 
        cv2.imshow('curFrame',frame)
        cv2.imshow('roi',roi)
        classifier.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer='rmsprop',metrics=['accuracy'])
        img = cv2.resize(roi,(100,100))
        img = np.reshape(roi,[1,100,100,3])

        classes = classifier.predict_classes(img)

        print(classes)


        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    except Exception:
        traceback.print_exc()
        pass        

cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

How do I reshape it in such way the it does not show error? Can you please explain why that error occurred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I guess the error comes from this line `img = np.reshape(roi,[1,100,100,3])` and this is because your `roi (= frame[100:400,200:500])` has (300,300) shape. And I see in the line above that your are using an other variable `img` which has the correct shape (100,100,3). So try this instead :

```
    img = cv2.resize(roi,(100,100))
    img = np.reshape(img,[1,100,100,3])
```

Furthermore, I don't think compiling your model in a while loop is something you want. It takes some time and it is unnecessary. So put it before the while loop and after loading weights.

Comment: do you mind going though this question? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57528724/how-to-create-multiple-frames-in-a-single-frame-to-display-input-as-welll-as-out/57528823?noredirect=1#comment101620016_57528823